# Running Nestjs And Postgres On Docker 127.0.0.1 Error

Tags: docker, nestjs

I'm new at Docker. I'm trying to run my postgres and nestjs app on docker. They work correctly but I guess they nestjs can't access to postgres container.

## docker-compose.yaml - docker-compose up --build

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: Sol
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: gamalol
    volumes:
       - ./postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "4321:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: gama@lol.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 1234
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
       - ./pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgres

    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    postgres:
    pgadmin:
```

## app.module.ts - docker run -d --network=host -p 3000:3000 prj:latest

```
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'postgres_container',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'Lenovo',
      password: '1234',
      database: 'gamalol',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
```

## Error:

```
[Nest] 1  - 01/03/2023, 9:38:07 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

I guess postgres working on 0.0.0.0:5432 but nestjs trying to connect at 127.0.0.1:5432. I tried to change host and port from app.module.ts but didn't work.

Comment: Somewhere else it looks like you've got typeorm/pg trying to connect by the default values. Your stack trace would be helpful here

Comment: The networking setup also will be simpler if you add the application to the `docker-compose.yml` file.  (You probably do not want `docker run --network=host`, but the right `docker run --network` value is not a constant; if you use Compose you can use the Compose-provided `default` network with no setup.)  This also suggests to me that the configuration block you quote isn't getting used, though, since I'd expect the `postgres_container` name to not resolve with the wrong Docker network configuration.